# Prawn: How to create an image with a link inside a table cell

Tags: pdf-generation, prawn

I'm using prawn to generate PDFs and I'm having trouble linking the image.

```
table_data = [
  [MY IMAGE WITH LINK HERE],
  ...
]
```

Where my image with a link exists inside a table cell `{:image => 'my image path' }` and needs to be clickable as a link.

Comment: Can you elaborate question a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

So far I was able to achieve this the following way...

```
link_annotation([bounds.absolute_right-180, 
            cursor+125, 
            bounds.absolute_right, cursor+90], 
            :Border => [0,0,0], 
            :A => { :Type => :Action, :S => :URI, 
            :URI =>
            PDF::Core::LiteralString.new('my url') } )
```

I had to create a clickable box and try to place it on top of the image through relative positioning

I'm not 100% sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hardcoding image dimensions, one can use the returned `Image` object `#scaled_height` and `#scaled_width` attributes. In my case image was at the top left corner so I did like this:

```rb
      image = @pdf.image logo, width: 100
      dimentions = [
        @pdf.bounds.absolute_left,
        @pdf.bounds.absolute_top - image.scaled_height,
        @pdf.bounds.absolute_left + image.scaled_width,
        @pdf.bounds.absolute_top
      ]
      url = PDF::Core::LiteralString.new("https://example.com")
      @pdf.link_annotation(dimentions, Border: [0,0,0], A: { Type: :Action, S: :URI, URI: url})
```

It seems like a little bit nicer way is possible by using `PA` instead of `A` in `#link_annotation` according to [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn/Core/Annotations#link_annotation-instance_method). But I couldn't figure out how it worked and it is not a significant improvement so not spending time on it.